# Making a new DataTable out of two others with same ID using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have two data tables that have results from queries made on two different servers. The items from the queries are related by a product ID, I am trying to combine the results into a new data table by joining on the product ids.

The basic structure of the tables are

//Product

product_id | field1 | field2 | field3...

//Inventory

id | fieldA | fieldB | fieldC...

and I want

product_id | field1 | field2 |field3 | fieldA | fieldB |fieldC

when product_id == id

This is pretty trivial to do in SQL but since the two data sets come from different databases on different servers I need to merge the results in my app for users.

The only semi-working solution I have is to get a left and right join from the tables, but I cannot figure out how to merge those results into a new data table. Here is some rough code of how I think it should be done. Any help on this would be appreciated as I am sure there is a much better way to do this.

```
var query = from S in Product.AsEnumerable()
            join I in Inventory.AsEnumerable()
            on S.Field<string>("product_id") equals I.Field<string>("id") into COLS
            from entry in COLS
            select entry;

var query2 = from I in Inventory.AsEnumerable()
             join S in Product.AsEnumerable()
             on I.Field<string>("id") equals S.Field<string>("product_id") into COLS2
             from entry in COLS2
             select entry;

var FullJoin = query.Union(query2);

if( FullJoin.Any())
{
    Results = FullJoin.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
}

return Results;
```

Comment: Did you tried posted code? Did you get some errors? How combining should behave when corresponding id missing on left or right side?

Comment: The code posted above populates query and query2 fine, and I can copy each to a new data table individually, however when I attempt to copy the joined results it throws an exception. Input array is longer than number of columns in this table. I do create Results as a null DataTable before the query runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try the following code:

```
var query = from p1 in P1 
                    join p2 in P2
                    on p1.ID equals p2.ProductID
                    select new { p1.ID, p1.Field1, p1.Field2, p1.Field3, p2.FieldA, p2.FieldB, p2.FieldC};
```

Comment: In order to use the syntax I have to specify like this ```I.Field<string>("id")``` and when I attempt to do the following I get an error that states that DataRow does not contain a definition for 'id'